# Linux Script to find string containing specific formatting & manipulate the data

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a linux script to search for lines in a file that are formatted like this:

text:text:text:text:number:number

so 6 text/number strings divided by 5 semicolon

For example:

```
2f0d:011a0000:07f8:0002:1:0
```

I want to treat the semicolon as column divider

e.g.

```
Column1:Column2:Column3:Column4:Column5:Column6
```

I then want to rearrange the data like so:

```
Column1:Column3:Column4:Column2 discarding column5 & column6
```

For example:

```
2f0d:07f8:0002:011a0000
```

I then want to replace semicolon with underscore, remove leading Zeros from each column & convert to UPERCASE

For example:

```
2F0D_7F8_2_11A0000
```

**End Result**

in file1, an entry like this

```
2f0d:011a0000:07f8:0002:1:0
E4+1
p:BSkyB,C:0000
```

will be converted to this:

```
2F0D_7F8_2_11A0000                    
E4+1
p:BSkyB,C:0000
```

Please note also, there are 100's if not 1000s of these 3 line entries in file1

Comment: Interesting - can you share what you've attempted already?

Comment: I have tried to create a perl script to recognize the string with no success, way way too wrong to post, sry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
kent$  awk -F: -v OFS="_" 'NF==6{for(i=1;i<=4;i++){sub(/^0*/,"",$i);$i=toupper($i)};print $1,$3,$4,$2;next}7' file  
2F0D_7F8_2_11A0000
E4+1
p:BSkyB,C:0000
```

you may want to know that, in awk:

- sub(pat, rep,input) will do replacement;
- toupper(string) will change string into upper case (yes, there is tolower() too)
- print $1,$2  will print col1 and col2 separated by OFS

the command much more important than the above one-liner:

```
man gawk
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing, thankyou very much for your time & explinations, at a glance that seemed to work perfectly.  Now I will spend the next few hours trying to digest exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

a solution using sed:

```
 sed -r 's/^0*([a-f0-9]+):0*([a-f0-9]+):0*([a-f0-9]+):0*([a-f0-9]+):[a-f0-9]+:[a-f0-9]+$/\1_\3_\4_\2/'
```

see [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qL6sE0)

Comment: Worked flawlessly also, thankyou for your time and DEMO was class, very useful for understanding whats going on

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -r 's/^0*([[:alnum:]]+):0*([[:alnum:]]+):0*([[:alnum:]]+):0*([[:alnum:]]+):0*([[:digit:]]+):0*([[:digit:]]+)$/\U\1_\3_\4_\2/' foo
```